# PHP Multiple Insert and Select Query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Can someone point out the mistake ? I am running without the loop and code is working fine but with for loop its not executing and also no error is displayed..

```
if(isset( $_POST['name'], $_POST['samplecount'], $_POST['decks'])) 
{  

  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $sample = $_POST['samplecount'];
  $decks = $_POST['decks'];
  $rows = ($sample/$decks);

  for ($i=0; $i<$decks; $i++){

    for ($j=1; $j<=$rows; $j++) {

         $stmt = $dbconnect -> prepare(" INSERT INTO decks (id, dnumber, vtext) 

        ( SELECT :id, :dnumber, 

        (SELECT r.vtext FROM rsample r WHERE r.groupname = :groupname  AND r.vtext 

          NOT IN (SELECT vtext FROM decks) 

        ORDER BY rand() LIMIT :rows)

        )
    "); 

  $stmt -> bindValue(':id', $i);
  $stmt -> bindValue(':dnumber', $j);
  $stmt -> bindValue(':groupname',$name)
  $stmt -> bindValue(':rows', $rows);
  $stmt -> execute ();

    }
  }
}
```

In my code I use `name = "test"` value of `samplecount = 8` and `decks = 2`. So `$rows` will be `4`.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have error reporting enabled and displaying? Is PDO configured to throw exceptions? (default behavior is to error silently).  At the top of your script `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and also use `$dbconnect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCPETION);`

Comment: The `LIMIT :rows` may malfunction. Typically that has to be type-specified in `bindValue()` as in `$bindValue(':rows', $rows, PDO::PARAM_INT)`